# Question per Day Ratio mismatch

Tags: support, bug

According to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37227/freelancing), our Question-per-Day Ratio is currently 16.3 but a moment ago, I saw the main page list 49 questions for our little community, and given that we've only been in private beta for 2 days, the math doesn't seem to add up. By my math, 49 questions over 2 days works out to something just under 25 questions per day, so I guess I'm missing something.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4):

The Area 51 statistics are not updated in real-time (updated once per day, I believe). Given the rounding error of when the day count increments and the mismatch between the number of questions and what is reported, those numbers will be way off in the earliest days.

Try not to hang on those stats so persistently. It's counter-productive to the focus of building a site. It's not a report card: [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)